# handling exceptions in ML

Tags: sml, smlnj

everyone, I'm trying to understand how exceptions work in ML, but I have strange error, and I can't figure out what is wrong:

```
exception Factorial 

fun checked_factorial n =
  if n < 0 then
    raise Factorial 
  else n;

fun factorial_driver () =
    checked_factorial(~4)
  handle
    Factorial => print "Out of range.";
```

what may be wrong? thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure that `factorial_driver` has a consistent type.  The non-exceptional case returns `int`, so ML infers the function to be of type `unit -> int`, but the exceptional case (that is, the `print` expression) returns `unit`, not `int`.

Generally, you basically need to return a value of the same type in all cases.